# Clearing everything but current line in tmux

Tags: shell, tmux

I have my Control-K shortcut bound in tmux like this:

```
bind -n C-k send-keys -R \; clear-history \;
```

This clears the scrollback buffer's history as well as the current screen, which is what I want. However, it does have one drawback; it clears everything on my screen, including the command prompt. Is there any way to get tmux to clear everything except the current line?

Answer (score 1):

The following will get you a terminal reset and clear history, but may result in an extra empty-line being printed

```
bind -n C-k send-keys -R Enter \; clear-history \;
```

Alternatively, if clearing the terminal (not "reset") is more to your liking, try this. It will result in a clean single prompt line being printed.

```
bind -n C-k send-keys ^c clear Enter \; clear-history \;
```